# Angular 6 - textarea (change) ever doesn't change the contents of the textarea

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am having an isse with a textarea where if I modify the contents on the textarea and the (change) is trigger it won't change the contents of the textarea by code.

Here is an example:

app.component.html

```
<textarea #content (change)="dosomething(content.value)">{{ thecontents | json }}</textarea>
```

app.component.ts

thecontents;

```
dosomething(data) {

    // this will overwrite whatever is already in the textarea
    this.thecontents = {  something : 'someother'};
}
```

For some reason the textarea is not being changed when the `(change)` is triggered

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try (keyup) instead of (change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to ngModel you can use View Child Directive to achive the same result

```
@ViewChild('content') con:ElementRef;
  thecontents={something:''};
name='';
  dosomething(data) {

    // this will overwrite whatever is already in the textarea

this.con.nativeElement.value=1;

}
```

I have edited your code check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjksed

Answer (score 8):

Bind the content of the textarea with `[value]` or with `[ngModel]`:

```
<textarea (change)="dosomething($event.target.value)" [value]="thecontents | json"></textarea>

<textarea (change)="dosomething($event.target.value)" [ngModel]="thecontents | json"></textarea>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qk7iun) for a demo.